# No such file or directory recording audio using Flutter Sound

Tags: flutter, audio

I'm trying to record audios in my app but I'm getting this error

```
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.myapp.example/app_flutter/1655521208092.wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I'm using path provider and this directory really doesnt exist, how can I create this directory or use a directory that already exists? Like, detect one already created directory or create one and then record the audio inside this directory?

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  filepath = directory.path + '/' + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.wav';
    _myRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this. If directory exists then get it otherwise create a new directory.

```
Future<void> startRecording() async {
        Directory appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String jrecord = 'Audiorecords';
        String dato = "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch?.toString()}.wav";
        Directory appDirec =
        Directory("${appDir.path}/$jrecord/");
        if (await appDirec.exists()) {
          playAudio.value = true;
          String patho = "${appDirec.path}$dato";
          print("path for file11 ${patho}");
          _recordingSession.openAudioSession();
          await _recordingSession.startRecorder(
            toFile: patho,
            codec: Codec.pcm16WAV,
          );
          _recordingSession.onProgress.listen((e) {
            var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.duration.inMilliseconds,
                isUtc: true);
            var timeText = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_GB').format(date);
            timerText.value = timeText.substring(0, 8);
          });
        } else {
          appDirec.create(recursive: true);
          String patho = "${appDirec.path}$dato";
          print("path for file22 ${patho}");
          _recordingSession.openAudioSession();
          await _recordingSession.startRecorder(
            toFile: patho,
            codec: Codec.pcm16WAV,
          );
    
          _recordingSession.onProgress.listen((e) {
            var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.duration.inMilliseconds,
                isUtc: true);
            var timeText = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_GB').format(date);
            timerText.value = timeText.substring(0, 8);
          });
        }
    
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked, but i dont have points to upvote 

Comment: Happy to help you.